# Univariate and Matrix Representation of Affine Transformation

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-fields, transformation

Let $\mathbb{F}$ be a finite field with $q$ elements and $\mathbb{E}$ an extension field of degree $n$ of $\mathbb{F}$. Let $S:\mathbb{F}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{F}^n$ be a affine transformation and define the following:

**Definition**: Let $0\leq i < n$ and $A,B_i \in \mathbb{E}$. Then we call the polynomial $S(X)=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}B_i X^{{q}^i}+A$ the univariate representation of the affine transformation $S(X)$.

**Definition**: Let $M_S \in \mathbb{F}^{n\times n}$ be a matrix and $v_s \in \mathbb{F}^n$ a vector and let $S(x):=M_Sx+v_s$. We call this a matrix representation of the affine transformation $S$ .

**Definition 3** Let $\mathbb{E}$ be an $n^{th}$ degree extension of the ground field $\mathbb{F}$ and $\mathbb{F}^n$ the corresponding vector space. Then we call $\phi:\mathbb{E}\rightarrow \mathbb{F}^n$ with $\phi(a):=b$ and $b_i=a_{i-1}$.

How I will able to demonstrate that an affine transfromation in univariate representation can be efficiently transfered into matrix representation?

In the book say that the rows of $M$ are $\phi(P(\phi^{−1}(e_k)))$ where $\phi$ is a canonical map between $\mathbb{E}$ and $\mathbb{F}^n$ and $e_k$ is a canonical basis of $\mathbb{F}^n$. Then, the expression is: $\phi(P(X))=M\phi(X)+v$.

I'm trying verify that expression for every row, then first I want calculate $P(\phi^{−1}(e_k))$, using the basis $V=\{t, t^q, t^{q^2},\ldots,t^{q^{n-1}}\}$ for $\mathbb{E}$ (Then any element of $\mathbb{E}$ I will be able to write than $a_0t^{q^0}+a_1t^{q^1}+\cdots+a_{n-1}t^{q^n-1}$)
$$P(\phi^{−1}(e_k)) = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} B_i(\phi^{−1}(e_k))^{q^i}$$
$$ = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} B_i(t^{q^{k-1}})^{q^i}$$
$$\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \left(\sum_{j=0}^{n-1} b_{i,j} \right) t^{q^{i}+q^{k-1+j}}$$

How I will be able to express that expression using the basis $V$ to secondly apply $\phi$ on the result of $P(\phi^{−1}(e_k))$.?

Answer (score 0):

An *affine transformation* is a linear map plus a translation.  Since $\mathbb{E}$ is an extension of degree n, we can write an $e \in \mathbb{E}$ as $e = e_0 + e_1 t + \ldots e_{n-1} t^{n-1}$, with $e_i \in \mathbb{F}$.  So as a vector space, we also have that $\mathbb{E} \cong \mathbb{F}^n$.  In particular, $A \in \mathbb{E}$ has a form $A = a_0 + a_1 t + \ldots + a_{n-1} t^{n-1}$.  The set $\{1,t,\ldots,t^{n-1}\}$ forms a basis for $\mathbb{E} \cong \mathbb{F}^n$ and we can think of $A$ as just a point in the vector space.  In this way, addition by $A$ and addition by $v_s\, (\, = A)$ is the translation.

The trickier bit is noticing that the map

$$X \mapsto \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} B_i X^{q^i}$$

is a linear transformation on $\mathbb{F}^n$, and that any linear transformation on that space can be expressed this way.

To see that the sum is linear, simply try it out.  Let $f,g \in \mathbb{E}$ and $\lambda \in \mathbb{F}$.  Then

$$ (f + \lambda g) \mapsto B_i (f+\lambda g)^{q^i} = B_i f^{q^i} + \lambda B_i g^{q^i}$$

This is because exponentiation by $q$ is a power of the Frobenius automorphism for a finite field, so $(a+b)^q = a^q + b^q$.  Moreover, the base field is fixed by exponentiation by $q$.  The sum of linear maps is still linear, so the whole thing is a linear map.  Linear algebra says we can always represent linear maps by a matrix with respect to some basis.

Now, to get the other way.. Chose $t \in \mathbb{E}$ such that $\{t, t^q, t^{q^2},\ldots,t^{q^{n-1}}\}$ is a basis for $\mathbb{E} \cong \mathbb{F}^n$, and take the matrix $M = (m_{i,j})$ with respect to that basis.  Then the matrix/vector product $Mt^{q^i}$ on each basis vector will be

$$\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \left(\sum_{j=0}^{n-1} m_{i,j} \right) t^{q^i}$$

Take $B_i = \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} m_{i,j}$.  Note that each $m_{i,j}\in \mathbb{E}$, so that $B_i$ is in $\mathbb{E}$ as well.

Comment: please clarify your answeer, I'm trying but I cann't get yet.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure I'm correct on the last step, but hopefully you see the idea now? :)

Comment: now I understand your anser, ... but the book say that the rows of $M$ are $\phi(P(\phi^{-1}(e_i)))$ where $\phi$ is a canonical map between $\mathbb{E}$ and $\mathbb{F}^n$ and $e_i$ is a canonical basis of $\mathbb{F}^n$. Then, the expression is: $\phi(P(X))=M\phi(X) + v$. Could you help me with this new version of the proof please?

Comment: the map $\phi$ is implicit in what I'm doing, it's essentially a change-of-basis matrix. if you let $e_i$ be the canonical basis (a column with all 0s except on the i-th row, that's a 1) for $\mathbb{F}^n$, then $\phi : \mathbb{F}^n \to \mathbb{E}^n$ by $e_i \mapsto \{\text{some expression in the t basis I gave}\}$ then it'll do the trick.

Comment: but in your answer I don't see $\phi(X)$.

Comment: +1 for suggesting the use of a normal basis, as it turns Frobenius into a cyclic shift of coordinates. A simple way of seeing that all linear (or affine) mappings arise from a polynomial like here is to observe that the space of those polynomial mappings has dimension $n$ over $\Bbb{E}$, hence dimension $n^2$ over $\Bbb{F}$. Which is equal to the dimension of the space of $n\times n$ matrices over $\Bbb{F}$. Observe that only the zero polynomial can have $q^n$ zeros, so a non-zero polynomial gives rise to a non-zero $\Bbb{F}$-linear mapping.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen thanks by your comment, I understand, but I want understand the version of the book. In the book say that the rows of $M$ are $\phi(P(\phi^{−1}(e_k)))$ where $\phi$ is a canonical map between $\mathbb{E}$ and $\mathbb{F}^n$ and $e_k$ is a canonical basis of $\mathbb{F}^n$. Then, the expression is: $\phi(P(X))=M\phi(X)+v$.

Comment: I have edit my question ... writing that I'm trying ...